# Change URL in Scripts

Tags: postman

I need to change URL of the API in the Postman script before the request is submitted. I see that URL variable is exposed but it's readonly. Is there anyway to accomplish what I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function within the `pre-request script` to change the URL before sending the request.

```
pm.request.url.update({protocol: "https", host: "jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"})
```

The main request is set to hit the `postman-echo` service but the script changes this and sends it to the `jsonplaceholder` site.

[image: Postman]

More information about the types of `options` you can have in the `update` function, can be found here:

http://www.postmanlabs.com/postman-collection/Url.html

Answer (score 0):

You might need to provide more information as your query seems very specific.

If it's a URL variable, it could be defined (or definable) in your Envrionment... Have you looked at the Environment dropdown in the top right?

Alternatively if it's read-only and you don't get any joy with the above, maybe it will let you use the Save dropdown on the right of the bar to "Save As"?

Comment: So my URL is {{url}}/api/test  Depending on what {{url}} is set to I need the final URL to be either {{url}}/api/test or {{url}}/test. So basically I am removing /api

Answer (score 0):

you can change the path by
pm.request.url.path = 'xxx'
change the host by
pm.request.url.host = 'xxx'

and other params such as protocal、port , just change as above